# converting binary and Hexadecimal without built-in functions

Tags: java, binary, hex

I am working on converting binary and Hexadecimal in my java program. I am able to read a one binary number but if I enter more the program only reads the last binary number and converts it to hexadecimal.  How do I read a long binary number and convert it to hexadecimal?  Like 101000011010
   Here is the part of my code.   Thanks.

```
public String binToHex() {
    String hex[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    String binary[] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001",
            "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"};
    String result = " ";

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = num.next();
    System.out.println("You entered " + userInput);


    for(int i=0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
        if (!userInput.isEmpty()) {
            ///System.out.print("not empty");
            temp = userInput.substring(i);
        }
        //System.out.print("temp: " + temp);
        String temp2 = ""+temp+"";
        //System.out.println("temp2 " + temp2);

        for(int j=0; j < binary.length; j++) {
            if(temp2.equals(binary[j])) {
                //System.out.print("inside if");
                result = result + hex[j];
                //System.out.println("results: " + result);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hex:" + result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String hex[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    String binary[] = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
        "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111" };
    String result = " ";
    boolean containcharacterOtherthan1or0 = false;
    System.out.println("enter the number :");
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = num.next();
    System.out.println("You entered " + userInput);
    for (int k = 0; k < userInput.length(); k++)
    {
      if (!String.valueOf(userInput.charAt(k)).equals("0") && !String.valueOf(userInput.charAt(k)).equals("1"))
        containcharacterOtherthan1or0 = true;
    }
    if (userInput.length() % 4 == 0 && !containcharacterOtherthan1or0)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i = i + 4)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < binary.length; j++)
        {
          if (binary[j].equals(userInput.substring(i, i + 4)))
          {
            result += hex[j];
          }
        }

      }

      System.out.println("the result is :" + result);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("enter a binary number with length of muliplier of 4 ");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off on this program. You are running the outside `for` loop once for every character entered into your input. If you enter a 12 digit binary number like you mentioned `101000011010` then the loop runs 12 times.

Inside that loop, you check to see if your input is empty. It is not, so it sets temp equal to `101000011010`. You then set a meaningless temp2 value (which temp would have sufficed) equal to temp. So now temp and temp2 are both equal to the input `101000011010`.

Now you check that value... (the entire 12 digit binary string) `101000011010` with each value inside your binary array. Obviously that 12 digit binary input is nowhere in your array so result does nothing.

Back into the outer `for` loop where you then set temp equal to the 12 digit string starting at index 1. IE you've now made temp equal to an 11 digit binary number `01000011010` (missing the first '1').

And it repeats this comparing these lengthy strings with the array and failing to find a match until you wind up toward the end where you pass in a 4 digit number.

Since your binary array ONLY has 4 digit numbers, the only number that's ever going to match anything in there is the 4 digit binary number at the end. IE A

The loop actually runs a few times after it finds the A but again its matching a 3 digit number, then a 2 digit number, 1 digit etc. and none of those are in the binary array either.

I recommend trying a new approach.